Spring boot 3.2.4 hibernate underscore naming convenction
I am trying to tell hibernate to create colums name with the underscore instead of camelCase but no success.
This is the entity used by hibernate for the column translationKey:
@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
@MappedSuperclass
abstract class AbstractProductEntity<T> {

  private T value;
  private String translationKey;

}

how can I tell spring boot to create a column in db like translation_key?
I tried with the property below but no success:
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy

Found this conf:
 @Slf4j
 @Configuration
 @EnableJpaRepositories(
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "generalEntityManagerFactory",
    transactionManagerRef = "generalTransactionManager",
    basePackages = "com.swisscom.wholesale.portal.repository.general")
 @EnableTransactionManagement
 public class GeneralDBConfig {

@Primary
@Bean(name = "generalEntityManagerFactory")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean generalEntityManagerFactory(final EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
                                                                          final @Qualifier(
                                                                                  "generalDB") DataSource dataSource,
                                                                          final @Value(
                                                                                  "${spring.datasource.general.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}") String hibernateHbm2dllAuto,
                                                                          final @Value(
                                                                                  "${spring.datasource.general.database-platform}") String databasePlatform) {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    /*props.put("hibernate.physical_naming_strategy", SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy.class.getName());
    props.put("hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy", SpringImplicitNamingStrategy.class.getName());*/
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(hibernateHbm2dllAuto)) {
        props.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", hibernateHbm2dllAuto);
    }
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(databasePlatform)) {
        props.put("hibernate.dialect", databasePlatform);
    }

    return builder
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .packages("com.swisscom.wholesale.portal.domain.general")
            .persistenceUnit("generalDB")
            .properties(props)
            .build();
}

@Primary
@Bean(name = "generalTransactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager generalTransactionManager(@Qualifier("generalEntityManagerFactory")
                                                                    EntityManagerFactory generalEntityManagerFactory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(generalEntityManagerFactory);
   }
 }


When using auto configuration that is already being applied. So not sure why you are trying to enable it (which means you either aren't using auto configuration or have disabled it somehow through a hibernate.properties or the likes).

@M.Deinum where are hibernate.properties located? What should I check to see if it is disabled? I mean the auto configuration right?

As stated the default is to use underscores. If you defined your own entitymanager configuration the auto configuration will do nothing (which will also render your spring.jpa properties useless as well). I think you are trying to be to smart and configure things manually instead of embracing the auto configuration from spring boot.

WIth a spring boot 2 it was automatically used underscore. Now with spring boot 3.2.4 it uses automatically camelcase. Why? I am new to the project. Maybe was setup an entity manager? how to check?

@M.Deinum I added a config that i found to this post.

I make use of spring boot 3.2 as well. You might want to rely on  the spring boot aauto configuration instead of manually configuring your transaction and entity manager.
You can then create a custom naming strategy like so;
import org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.Identifier;
import org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment;
import org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironmentBuilder;
import org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.NameQualifierSupport;

public class CustomPhysicalNamingStrategy extends org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl {

    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalColumnName(Identifier name, JdbcEnvironment context) {
        return Identifier.toIdentifier(convertToSnakeCase(name.getText()));
    }

    private String convertToSnakeCase(String input) {
        // Convert camelCase to snake_case
        return input.replaceAll("(.)(\\p{Upper})", "$1_$2").toLowerCase();
    }
}

Then, tell spring to make use of the custom naming strategy by specifying in your config
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=com.example.CustomPhysicalNamingStrategy

Dont forget to change the com.example to your corresponding package
